# Predicting variable Time Series - Unknown Frequency

Tags: time-series, forecasting, python, r

I would like to create a model in order to predict the demand of a certain variable according to some historical data.
I am working with Python and I am facing some problems.

1) My time series does not have a defined frequency. I have been working with R and time series in the past, and I used to specify a frequency for the observation. How should I deal with my case? (I can have 50 entries one day, 0 another day, and so on)

2) I would like to forecast the demand of a given "Function Title". Do you advise me to use any machine learning technique? (my dataset is about 26000 entries)

Here a preview of my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

#Replace column with english label
df.columns = ['Work Experience', 'Function Profile', 'Function Title',
              'Occupation', 'Education', 'Company Name', 'Clean Company Name',
              'Sector (Industry)', 'Location', 'Salary Indication', 'Province',
              'Date Found', 'ISCO', 'SBI-Code']
ts = df.set_index(dates)
ts.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that is called a "time series" in normal statistical parlance always has regular values. There are techniques for filling in missing values (e.g. you want to analyze a daily temperature record with time series techniques, but there are some days the guy recording them was out sick). But this looks like an inherently stochastic problem: the time at which entry appears is inherently random.

If I understand your problem correctly, you can transform this into a time series by counting the number of entries per day (or week, or whatever). This count is then a time series, in the usual understanding of the term, and can be analyzed as such. And since what you want to predict is itself a number of entries in some future time period, this is probably the right approach.

Comment: The OP gives very little to go on, but I suspect your approach is right.

Comment: If I understood right, you advise me to group by the entries by month (therefore, frequency=12) and transform the dataset accordingly.
 In this case, in order to predict the "Function Title", I need to create a column for each "Function Title" in the dataset, and for each month count how many entries for the given function title I have.
After, I can create the preditive model. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes,that is correct. (The one thing I don't get in your response is what "frequency=12" means. Is that some setting in the tool you are using to analyze the data? You have correctly understood the procedure I have described, but I have no advice about how to implement that procedure in your tools.)